# Calculating X Y movement based on rotation angle?

Tags: c#, rotation, game-physics, angle

Say I have an object in 2D space that can rotate and then should move according to its rotation angle.

For example:

- If angle is 0(pointing upwards), then `on_timer` it should move 1 by Y and 0 by X.
- If angle is 45, then it should move 1 by Y and 1 by X.
- If pointing 90 degrees, then 0 by Y and 1 by X.
- If pointing 135 degrees, then -1 by Y and +1 by X, etc.

Do you know any functions for calculating this?

Comment: This is a good question.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

well, it seems to move at different speeds for different angles.

For 0 degress (straight up) it moved by 1, but 45 begrees it moved sqrt(1^2 + 1^2) = 1.41.

I think you want to look at Sin and Cos.

```
X += Speed * Math.Cos(angle);
Y += Speed * Math.Sin(angle);
```

Regards Gert-Jan

Comment: Thanks, got it working! :)             double radians = (Math.PI / 180) * ( this.orient - 90 ) ;
            this.CorX = Convert.ToInt16(this.CorX + 15 * Math.Cos(radians));
            this.CorY = Convert.ToInt16(this.CorY + 15 * Math.Sin(radians));

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.matrix.aspx  (examples at the bottom of the page)