# Moving an object with a rotation

Tags: lua, cheat-engine

I'm trying to make a freecam sort of tool for a rather obscure game. I'm trying to figure out how to move the XY position of the freecam based on the car's rotation value, but I'm struggling to do so. I've tried using [Calculating X Y movement based on rotation angle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5192983/calculating-x-y-movement-based-on-rotation-angle) and modifying it a bit, but it doesn't work as intended. The game's rotation uses a float that ranges from -1 to 1, -1 being 0 degrees and 1 being 360 degrees.

Putting rot at -1 corresponds to X+
Putting rot at 0 corresponds to Z+
Putting rot at 1 corresponds to X-

Here's my cheat engine code:

```
speed = 10000
local yaw = math.rad((180*(getAddressList().getMemoryRecordByDescription('rot').Value))+180)
local px = getAddressList().getMemoryRecordByDescription('playerx').Value
local py = getAddressList().getMemoryRecordByDescription('playery').Value
local pz = getAddressList().getMemoryRecordByDescription('playerz').Value
local siny = math.sin(yaw) -- Sine of Horizontal (Yaw)
local cosy = math.cos(yaw) -- Cosine of Horizontal (Yaw)
getAddressList().getMemoryRecordByDescription('playerx').Value = ((getAddressList().getMemoryRecordByDescription('playerx').Value)+(cosy*speed))
getAddressList().getMemoryRecordByDescription('playerz').Value = ((getAddressList().getMemoryRecordByDescription('playerz').Value)+(siny*speed))
print(yaw)
```

Comment: Which values of `rot` should correspond to positive x and positive z directions?

Comment: Edited my post with new information about rot values.

Comment: What value of `rot` corresponds to Z- ?

Comment: Interesting.. Zero.. as well... This is a detail i've completely missed!

Comment: So, it's impossible to derive the angle without additional info.  I guess, `rot` equals to `-cosy`